# Google App Engine urlfetch loop

Tags: python, google-app-engine, loops

Can I make a loop in Google App Engine that fetches information from a site?

I have made a small code that already gets the information I want from the site, but I don't know how to make this code run every lets say, 20 minutes.

Is there a way to do this?

P.S.: I have looked at TaskQueue, but I'm not sure if it is meant for things like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what the cron addon is for - [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron) is some documentation to help you get started.

Comment: Thanks alot. You too, Dragonx!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the GAE cron functionality.